# Why does count(*) return an unsigned integer?

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query is an example where default values (in this example INTEGER(21)) are mixed with computed values (in this example COUNT(*)).

```
SELECT
  dimension,
  SUM(metric)
FROM (
  SELECT
    "dim1" AS dimension,
    INTEGER(21) AS metric),
  (
  SELECT
    dimension,
    COUNT(*) AS metric
  FROM (
    SELECT
      "dim2" AS dimension,
      INTEGER(42) AS metric)
  GROUP BY
    dimension)
GROUP BY
  dimension
```

When running this query, it gets rejected with the following error message:

> Cannot union tables : Incompatible types. 'metric' : TYPE_INT64 'metric' : TYPE_UINT64

In other words, the count operation returns an unsigned integer whereas an integer created manually is signed. I understand the underlaying logic of the count operation, which obviously always return an integer being greater or equal than 0. The same goes with the fact that this can be avoided by casting COUNT(*) by encapsulating it with the INTEGER constructor on line 11 of my sample query.

I guess my real question is: why does COUNT(*) return an unsigned integer instead of a signed one (which would allow for cleaner and simpler queries as is the case in other SQL-like environments)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just an unfortunate mistake to make COUNT return unsigned integer type, especially since BigQuery doesn't even support unsigned integers in its metadata. But this (and many other issues) is fixed with standard SQL support in BigQuery, which is available as Alpha. For details how to enable it - check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why using an unsigned int is advantageous:

- **Philosophical**: As you mentioned, COUNT cannot return negative numbers, only [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), which is what unsigned ints are designed to represent. It's the right tool for the job.
- **Range**: An unsigned int can store roughly twice as many non-negative values as a signed int. This greatly decreases the likelihood that the variable will overflow while representing the output of the function.
- **Type safety**: By using a type that cannot represent invalid data it prevents you, the user, from trying to make invalid comparisons. If you try to compare the output of COUNT with a negative number the analyzer can tell you immediately that the comparison you are doing doesn't make sense and is likely to be wrong, thereby potentially saving you from annoying bugs down the line.

Comment: I'm far from disagreeing with your response, but my main concern here is that this is an undocumented feature/bug which is tricky to debug and makes transition from other SQL environments more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a count it isn't possible to have a negative number.  So by making it an unsigned int then the range of numbers that can be handled is expanded.

Comment: Given that the integer is already on 64 bits, I don't think this is really a limitation for the COUNT(*) operation for most people.